# GlobalProtect VPN over VPN on MacOS

Tags: networking, vpn, ipsec, palo-alto-networks

I am using GlobalProtect VPN client to access my company's network. I also have a personal IPSec VPN server. I would like to access to my company's network after my personal VPN, I mean I want to first have my personal VPN then run GlobalProtect VPN to access the company's network.

But when my own VPN (on Mac) is on, GlobalProtect VPN doesn't work.

Is there any way to have one more VPN layer before GlobalProtect VPN? should I change my VPN server protocol, or is there any setting in my GlobalProtect VPN client?

Comment: I don't believe the native macOS client can handle multiple VPN connections (I'm happy to be told wrong). You might get around it by using an OpenVPN over IPsec but I'm not even sure.

Comment: Actually I have tested running two VPNs the other way around: first GlobalProtect and then an IPSec VPN on top of that. The main drawback is that GlobalProtect highjacks DNS so you need to know the IP addresses of any servers you want to reach on the other network: In other words it breaks most TLS services, but it's an acceptable way of gaining access to a jump host.